# Abduction of Prolog clauses

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, constraint-programming

I have a specification of a directed, rooted graph with labeled nodes and edges.  The specification describes what nodes can be connected to what other nodes, and aspects of the structure of the graph in terms of properties of the vertices.

For instance:

Every A node has to be connected to a B node with edge type B which is connected by any edge type to a D node, and the root has to have a path to at least 2 other nodes.

```
followsSpec(Root) :- 
    edge(Root, _, A), 
    edge(Root, _, B), 
    A != B, 
    edge(A, edgeTypeB, C), 
    node(C, nodeTypeC), 
    edge(C, _, D),
    node(D, nodeTypeD).
```

I would like to say

```
node(root, typeA)
followsSpec(root)
```

and abduce other possible elements of the graph which make `followsSpec` true:

```
node(b, typeB)
node(c, typeC)
edge(root, some_arbitrary_edge_type, b)
edge(root, some_other_arbitrary_edge_type, c)
edge(b, edge_type_b, c)
```

Is there a way to do this in Prolog?

In particular, I am worried about efficiency since in reality the spec is more complicated and there will be at least 100 nodes.

Edit: trying to formalize:
the abducible predicates are `edge/3` (where the three variables correspond to the source, target, and type of transformation) and `node/2` (where the two variables correspond to the node identifier and node label).
I start with a single fact `node(root, rootLabel))`.
My observation: followsSpec(root), where

`followsSpec(X) :- "x is connected in a particular way to other nodes through edges"`

What I want to observe: what those other nodes and edges are so that followsSpec(root) is true.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184840/discussion-on-question-by-lightning-abduction-of-prolog-clauses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hypothetical reasoning to find abductive solutions. Lets say you have a theory T, and want to find explanation E for some observation O:

```
 T, E |- O
```

Hypothetical reasoning has a special operator called embedded implication (assumez). You can verify an abductive solution by using this implication, turning abduction into deduction:

```
 T |- assumez(E, O).
```

A simple implementation of assumez/2 would be:

```
assumez(E,O) :-
   assertz(E),
   O,
   retract(E).
```

But the above will not survive a cut, so you need a Prolog system that has trailed assertz/1 and retract/1. If you don't want to go [CHR](http://webhotel4.ruc.dk/~henning/publications/ChristiansenDahlICLPfin05.pdf) or ASP, you could use the simpler library(minimal/hypo) from Jekejeke Prolog.